# postgres move all but minimum records of a groupby to another table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres called t1. I need to do a groupby of t1 on fields a, b, and c. I then need to select all records in the groupby, *except* for the record with the minimum value in field d, and move those to table t2. If the groupby only has a single row, I don't want to move it to t2. How can I express this type of update in psql?

e.g. current t1:

```
| a | b | c | d |
|---|---|---|---|
|'m'|'q'|'w'|1  |
|'m'|'q'|'w'|2  |
|'m'|'q'|'w'|3  |
|'m'|'r'|'x'|1  |
|'m'|'r'|'x'|2  |
|'m'|'s'|'y'|1  |
```

desired t1 after running update:

```
| a | b | c | d |
|---|---|---|---|
|'m'|'q'|'w'|1  |
|'m'|'r'|'x'|1  |
|'m'|'s'|'y'|1  |
```

desired t2 after running update:

```
| a | b | c | d |
|---|---|---|---|
|'m'|'q'|'w'|2  |
|'m'|'q'|'w'|3  |
|'m'|'r'|'x'|2  |
```

Comment: exists / not exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*
from t1 as t
join 
(
select a
    , b
    , c
    , min(d) as min_d
    , count(*) as count
from t1
group by 1,2,3
) x
on t.a = x.a
and t.b = x.b
and t.c = x.c
and t.d != x.min_d
and x.count > 1
```

Comment: This works; just missing the part where we move the data from t1 to t2.

Comment: yea you just had to insert this into t2. anyways, glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full update that ended up working:

```
with new_t1 as
(
    delete from t1 where (a, b, c, d) in
    (
        select t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d from t1 as t
        join(
            select a,
                   b,
                   c,
                   min(d) as min_d,
                   count(*) as count
            from t1 group by a, b, c
        ) j
        on t.a = j.a
        and t.b = j.b
        and t.c = j.c
        and t.d > j.min_d
    )
    returning *
)
insert into t2 select * from new_t1;
```